# What operation is that?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I was reading this paper

> Peet, M. M., & Papachristodoulou, A. (2012). A Converse Sum of Squares
>   Lyapunov Result With a Degree Bound. IEEE Transactions on Automatic
>   Control, 57(9), 2281–2293. https://doi.org/10.1109/TAC.2012.2190163.

In page 2291 in the second part of the calculus, in the first line, we have the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
48I & 6I\\
6I & I
\end{bmatrix}$$
 where I is the identity matrix of size 2x2, and the next line this matrix is replaced by 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
6.93I & 2.45I\\
2.45I & I
\end{bmatrix}^2$$ 
What is the operation that made possible this outcome?

Comment: it's called sqrt ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: it is not the sqrt, as one can check easily!

Comment: @DominikS sqrt(48) is 6.93 if rounded to two places etc. the coefficients are the sqrt of the ones before. under some products this will create the other.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: My bad, you're right, is seems to be a component-wise square root... Which is strange, since I would have expected a *matrix square root*, given the notation!

Comment: I suspect it is a sqrt under the kronecker product. edit: okay never mind not kronecker ( though A is a kronecker product)

Comment: @jonaprieto: What is the context of this matrix? Does an element-wise product (see answer below) make sense?

Comment: @DominikS See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2619.pdf) for the article, p. 10. I did not read carefully but I don't understand the use of the Hadamard product.

Comment: okay I see it could also be a hadamard product ( stupid me forgetting the name).

Comment: @Idéophage: Thanks for the article! I don't see a motivation for a Hadamard product either. The entire calculation on p. 10 looks simply like a manipulation of a quadratic form to me - with the usual matrix-vector multiplication rules. The error might just be sloppiness - it looks tempting enough.

Answer (score 1):

@Roddy MacPhee hinted the right direction.

The underlying matrix multiplication seems to be the [Hadamard matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). With respect to this product, the square root of a matrix is simply the square root of its entries.

However, the second matrix (the one that is apparantly squared) is *not* the square root of $A$ with respect to the standard matrix product, as the notation might misleadingly suggest at the first look.